# How to verify Image is visible/exists on front end using <img src> or <a href> tag

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

Does anyone know how I can verify if an image exists using its `<a href>` or `<img src>`? I can only verify by its class such as:

```js
it('Verifying vertical product', () => {
    cy.get('.stage --vertical').should('be.visible')
})
```

but I want to know how to verify with img src or href tag. thank you

Full HTML:

```html
<a href="haigclub.diageoplatform.com/en/our-whisky/haig-club-clubman"> 
  <img style="margin: auto; display: block;" class="stage__image" 
    src="haigclub.diageoplatform.com/user/themes/haig/images/bottle.png"> 
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the HTML to your question.

Comment: I can see the HTML.

Comment: <a href="https://haigclub.diageoplatform.com/en/our-whisky/haig-club-clubman">
                                        <img style="margin: auto; display: block;" class="stage__image" src="https://haigclub.diageoplatform.com/user/themes/haig/images/bottle.png">
                                        </a>

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for

```js
cy.get('a[href="..."]')
```

Similarly

```js
cy.get('img[src="..."]')
```

where you should add the appropriate text instead of `...`

Of course, follow with `.should('be.visible')`.

If you want to use a partial match, you can use

```js
cy.get('img[src$="bottle.png"]')  // NOTE src$=
```

Comment: it('Verifying vertical product', () => {
 cy.get('img[src="https://haigclub.diageoplatform.com/user/themes/haig/images/bottle.png"]').should('be.visible')
    })

Comment: According to your advice, I believe this is the right way to verify

Comment: It should be - is there any error?

Comment: If you want to use a partial match, you can use `cy.get('img[src$="bottle.png"})`. Note I added a closing quote which you missed in the comment.

Comment: LOL I also missed some closing quotes.

Comment: omg you helped me verify the .png file!

Comment: thanks so much, are you a QA engineer?

Answer (score 2):

A more explicit test might select `href` and `.find()` the img, to avoid the problem of returning multiple images.

```js
cy.get('a[href^="haig-club-clubman"]')
  .find('img')                             // find inside previous selector (a[href])
  .should('have.attr', 'src')
  .and('include', 'bottle.png')            // explicit test of src attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assert the image with the image name you can do something like:

```js
cy.get('img').invoke('attr', 'src').should('include', 'bottle.png')
```

Comment: But will it work if there's more than one `img`?

Comment: `cy.get('img')` will yield all `img` tags. You'll need to use a more specific css selector (such as the one listed in your question) to get an individual element, but you can still use the `invoke().should()` strategy that Alapan used above.

Comment: @agoff - true, but if you use a better CSS selector you can ignore `.invoke().should()` because the CSS selector already tests that.

Comment: Right, but I think the beauty of Alapan's solution is that it is explicit in what it is testing -- that _some element_ has a src attribute that includes _some text_. Fody's solution is succinct and gets to the point, but I find it lacks the intention of this answer. A different possible way to write it would be `cy.get('img').should('have.attr', 'src').and('include', 'bottle.png');`

Comment: Explicit is better, to me `cy.get('img[src="..."]')` is explicit enough.

Comment: But it still fails when there's more than one `img`, which might mislead someone trying to use the answer in that situation.

Comment: There wasn't much HTML in the question to begin. The original question asked to verify an image exists, which does not necessary ask for specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to apply a filter which checks the attribute.

Not optimal here, but useful for more complicated scenarios.

```js
cy.get('img')
  .filter('[src^="bottle.png"]')
```